# How to programmatically split a movie file into separate parts?

Tags: scripting, split, movieclip

i'm exploring ways to split a movie file into N separate/complete/shorter files programmatically. Do any of you have suggestions for what software or scripting language to do this?

I do not necessarily want to break them down and reassemble them again, rather i just want to split, for example, myMovie.avi into myMovie1.avi, myMovie2.avi, ..., myMovieX.avi

I'm currently exploring Flash, Ruby, Python, Java and more for the best option. Please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty straightforwad process that you can achieve with any scripting language and something like ffmpeg.
I think this could be of help: http://icephoenix.us/notes-for-myself/auto-splitting-video-file-in-equal-chunks-with-ffmpeg-and-python/